# populate grid view such that some fields come in first row, some in second and so on, based upon the employee number

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, oracle, gridview

I have a Oracle Oledb database table which is employee's Master, which contains name age,sex and relationship of employee and his dependants. I want to create a separate row into gridview or any other suitable control for each one of them i.e employee and his dependents when I pass the employee number. is it possible..??

**For example** if employee name is abc, his father xyz, mother pqr 
then it should be displayed like

```
name age      relation

abc  his age    self

xyz  his age    father

pqr  her age   mother
```

please note all of them are in a single row in the table, I want them in separate rows now

Comment: Change your sql query so that it returns the desired rows.

Comment: I agree with Tim.  If you have trouble doing that, post your query in your question for further help.

Answer (score 0):

While I agree with those who urged you to break your query into multiple rows if you can, there is a way to do what you want.  While you don't mention any need to edit rows using your "suitable control", this solution can - with a bit of work - allow you to do so.

Use a `DataList` or even a `Repeater` and build a table in your `ItemTemplate`:

```
 <asp:DataList runat="server" RepeatLayout="Table" ExtractTemplateRows="true">
     <HeaderTemplate>
          <asp:Table runat="server">
              <asp:TableRow runat="server">
                  <asp:TableCell runat="server">
                      Name
                  </asp:TableCell>
                  <!--- etc -->
              </asp:TableRow>
          </asp:Table>
      </HeaderTemplate>
      <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Table runat="server">
            <asp:TableRow runat="server">
                <asp:TableCell><asp:Label id="lblName1" runat="server" /></asp:TableCell>
                <!-- etc. -->
            </asp:TableRow>
            <asp:TableRow runat="server">
                <asp:TableCell><asp:Label id="lblName2" runat="server" /></asp:TableCell>
                <!-- etc. -->
            </asp:TableRow>
            <asp:TableRow runat="server">
                <asp:TableCell><asp:Label id="lblName3" runat="server" /></asp:TableCell>
                <!-- etc. -->
            </asp:TableRow>          
        </asp:Table>
     </ItemTemplate>
  </asp:DataList>
```

At run time, the table rows will be extracted from the inner tables and merged into a single table.  You can even set up command buttons (perhaps in a row with a rowspan="3" attribute) so that you have what looks and works like a triple-row grid.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a badly designed database.  Your employee should be in one table and his dependents should be in a table related by his employee id.  Then it would be simple to do what you want to do.